# Remove quotation marks from numeric vector in R

Tags: r

I converted a vector consisting of the values "Yes" and "No" into 1 and 0 by doing this:

```
Variable1[Variable1 == "No"] <- 0
Variable1[Variable1 == "Yes"] <- 1
```

Now the vector has quotation marks around all of the 0s and 1s.  This is causing R to treat the vector as non-numeric, as I'm getting the following error message when trying to run a correlation test between variables.

> Error in cor.test.default(Variable1, Variable2, method = "spearman") :
>   'x' must be a numeric vector

What's the best way to remove the quotation marks around the 0s and 1s?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to convert your variable into numeric: `as.numeric(Variable1)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ifelse` :

```r
Variable1 <- sample( c("Yes", "No"), 10, replace = TRUE )
ifelse( Variable1 == "Yes", 1, 0)
#>  [1] 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0
```

Please make sure you include a reprex next time, with e.g. [the reprex](https://github.com/tidyverse/reprex) package.